# Sum in tree view odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9, qweb

I need sum row in tree view, and add where condition if is it possible!

My tree view:

row | field_1 | field_2

1  |  8    |    Messi

2  |  8   |     Messi

3  |  8    |    Ronaldo

4  |  8     |   Ronaldo

How sum only for Messi and only for Ronaldo and get result 16

In below span I get 32

```
<span t-esc="sum(line.field_1 for line in doc.my_ids)" widget="float_time"/>
```

Any solution?

```
<span t-esc="Messi"/>  16
<span t-esc="Ronaldo"/>  16
```

Comment: You don't need write code for that. From the view you can group by `field_2`. So Odoo calculate the sum value of the field_1 for you automatic

Comment: @julivico I need result in qweb, any example?

Comment: Ah ok. For Qweb you can look at the example from this link [https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-group-by-product-category-in-qweb-report-102920](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-group-by-product-category-in-qweb-report-102920)

Comment: @qvpham You should convert your comment into an answer and include at least an excerpt from the link in case the link dies in the future.

Comment: @travisw: i just don't want to copy the solution from someone

Comment: @qvpham I agree it's not ideal, but as long as you clearly credit the source it's an accepted practice. In this case it seems to be the correct amswer, so it should be posted as such. Stack Exchange frowns upon link only answers in case the link becomes broken in the future. It is to preserve the answer on SE without relying on the outside website.

Comment: @travisw: nice to know your opinion. But you are right. I will add the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group your lines by `field_2` and than calculate the sum of `field_1` for each `player`.

```xml
<t t-set="players" t-value="[]"/>
<t t-foreach="doc.my_ids" t-as="l">
    <t t-set="players" t-value="players+[l.field_2]"/>
</t>
<t t-foreach="set(players)" t-as="player">
    <p>
    <span t-esc="player"/>
    <t t-set="sum_goal" t-value=0/>
    <t t-foreach="doc.my_ids" t-as="l">
        <t t-if="player==l.field_2">
            <t t-set="sum_goal" t-value=sum_goal+l.field_1/>
        </t>
    </t>
    <span t-esc="sum_goal"/>
    </p>
</t>
```

`players` is a **list** of `field_2`. You must use `set()` to remove the duplication.